# Log All Requests for User Per Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to build an "audit trail" for all requests incoming to the server, however it needs to be specific per user, per web page.

For instance I imagine something like this:

1. On initial view render I would store (cookie/ page variable/ something else) a unique Id saying the user browsed to /myapp.com/dashboard/1234. - maybe in the layout.cshtml.
2. Then the app fires off X number of GET/ POST requests to the server each having that same unique Id initially tied to the view rendered.

This allows me then to tie back all requests for a page and add up the server execution time.

I tried using path specific cookies but this won't work I realized since a user can have many tabs open with the same url. Also the user works in many areas of the app at once. They can have anywhere from 1 to 10+ tabs open. Each of these should have it's own unique Id and "audit trail" of all calls taking place on that page.

This is an existing app so modifying each of the GET/ POST to pass in the unique Id is out of scope. Just hoping I am missing something that might take care of this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a single page load, and then additional requests made either for images and other resources or AJAX requests that you want tied to and tracked along with that initial page load.

The chief problem you're going to have here is that, based on the way HTTP works, each request is handled as its own thing and not considered as part of a greater whole. The web browser makes it all look seamless, but all the web server is doing is just responding to a bunch of (as far as it knows) unrelated requests for various different things. To track them all as one unit, you would either need to attach some unique id to the request itself (for a GET, that would be either as part of the URI path or query string) or lean on `Session` to introduce state between the requests. However, session state really only works in this scenario when all requests can be tied to a single initial request. Once the user starts working with multiple different pages at once, there's no reasonable to discern which request belongs to what, and you're back in the same boat.

In other words, your only real option is to send something along with the request, which would mean doing something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/file.css?origin=@Request.RawUrl" />
```

Then, you could have an action filter that looks for `origin` in the query string of any request, and ties it to the logging for that particular page.

For what it's worth, it should be noted that by default, IIS will handle all requests for static resources directly, without involving ASP.NET. If you do want to track requests for static resources, you would have to pass them all through ASP.NET, which will be kind of a pain. If you only want to track AJAX requests, that's much simpler and shouldn't require anything special for the most part.

All that said, if the only purpose of this is to track page load time, there's far better and easier ways to do that. You can install Glimpse. You can use your browser's developer console. You can use something like Google Analytics. All of these are far preferable to the path you're going down here, for page load statistics.

Comment: I kind of figured this wasn't possible without modifying each request to attach an id to pass back. This is initially what I thought and did not want to go down this route. Just thought maybe, just maybe, someone solved this problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write an ActionFilter to do this.  There are many examples of this

http://rion.io/2013/04/15/creating-advanced-audit-trails-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/

I personally like Mark Seemann's example more since it clearly defines a nice separation of concerns for the attribute and the filter.

Comment: I already am using filters to handle the logging (not what I need help on). 

This still doesn't uniquely identify the requests coming from /myapp.com/dashboard1/123 vs /myapp.com/otherthings/123. I need to know the page + user specific request trail. I have no problem getting the principle on the server containing the user information.

Comment: why doesn't this work filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url or filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl to get the url

Comment: Tried that. It works for POSTs, but during GETs Request.Url, RawUrl, AbsoluteUri do not match what is currently in the web address bar. They are the uri of the action taking place. The only one that matches is UrlReferrer but that isn't always a reliable source for me since we may actually redirect them (and in that case would be a new view thus starting a whole new audit trial)... Plus this won't work if they have two of the same pages open since it would show the same url for both.